# Como abrir uma GUI construída no Eclipse pelo Netbeans?

Tags: java, eclipse, netbeans

Estou com um código usando `JFrame`, porém quando vou abri-lo pelo Netbeans só consigo mudar o *layout* pelo código. Como faço para usar o código e editar o layout pelo construtor de GUI do *Swing*.

Comment: Você fez ele código usando o drag and drop (ferramenta de arrastar) do próprio netbeans ou fez "a mão"?

Comment: fiz pelo drag and drop porem do eclipse

Comment: Tentou usar a opção de importar código do eclipse?

Comment: não tem mais o eclipse apenas o codigo seco.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No Netbeans para ele ser reconhecido como um formulário e funcionar corretamente há vários requisitos. Vou começar pelo mais simples (mas menos importante). Primeiramente, o construtor deverá ter a seguinte forma:

```java
public MinhaTela() {
    initComponents();
}
```

Você até pode alterar o construtor como quiser, mas é importante manter a chamada ao `initComponents()`. Como é o formato do `initComponents()`? Tipicamente é assim:

```java
/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {
    // ... Um monte de código ...
}// </editor-fold>  

// Mais um monte de código...

// Variables declaration - do not modify   
// ... Algumas variáveis aqui ...
// End of variables declaration
```

Estas duas áreas acima (o código do `initComponents()` e as variáveis declaradas no final da classe) serão coloridas de cinza pelo Netbeans. Ele normalmente não te deixará alterá-las diretamente pelo código. Se você abrir em um editor externo (exemplo, Notepad++) você verá mais códigos que o Netbeans nunca mostra:

```java
/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">//GEN-BEGIN:initComponents
private void initComponents() {
    // ... Um monte de código ...
}// </editor-fold>//GEN-END:initComponents

// Mais um monte de código...

// Variables declaration - do not modify//GEN-BEGIN:variables
// ... Algumas variáveis aqui ...
// End of variables declaration//GEN-END:variables
```

Vê esses `//GEN-BEGIN:initComponents`, `//GEN-END:initComponents`, `//GEN-BEGIN:variables` e `//GEN-END:variables`? Eles são delimitadores que o Netbeans usa para proteger o código contra modificações. Se você removê-los com uma ferramenta externa o Netbeans permitirá você a mexer diretamente neste código.

Tal como o comentário do `initComponents()` diz, o corpo deste método é gerado e regerado automaticamente (bem como as variáveis no final) sempre que o construtor de GUI decidir alterá-lo. As configurações de formulário do editor estão dentro de um arquivo com a extensão `.form` na mesma pasta da sua classe. Assim, se o seu arquivo que contém a sua subclasse de `JFrame` se chama `MinhaTela.java`, deverá haver um arquivo `MinhaTela.form` na mesma pasta.

É neste arquivo `.form` que os detalhes do editor de tela estão armazenados (em um formato XML). Então para que o Netbeans reconheça a sua tela no editor dele, este arquivo deverá estar presente.

Mas e se você não tiver este arquivo `.form`? **Se você não tiver este arquivo, o Netbeans não irá reconhecer o seu `JFrame` como editável pelo construtor de GUI.** Neste caso, se você não quiser simplesmente esquecer a edição pelo construtor de GUI e ficar apenas no código, você poderá criar um arquivo `.form` vazio para começar a recriar o *layout* todo.

Se você for recriar o *layout* todo, convém fazer um *backup* uma vez que o Netbeans irá alterar automaticamente a sua classe a partir das informações contidas no arquivo `.form` e também certifique-se que o `initComponents()` e as variáveis do final da classe estão presentes seguindo o modelo mostrado acima (possivelmente incluindo os comentários `GEN-BEGIN` e `GEN-END`). Eis um arquivo `.form` vazio para começar:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<Form version="1.3" maxVersion="1.9" type="org.netbeans.modules.form.forminfo.JFrameFormInfo">
  <Properties>
    <Property name="defaultCloseOperation" type="int" value="3"/>
  </Properties>
  <SyntheticProperties>
    <SyntheticProperty name="formSizePolicy" type="int" value="1"/>
    <SyntheticProperty name="generateCenter" type="boolean" value="false"/>
  </SyntheticProperties>
  <AuxValues>
    <AuxValue name="FormSettings_autoResourcing" type="java.lang.Integer" value="0"/>
    <AuxValue name="FormSettings_autoSetComponentName" type="java.lang.Boolean" value="false"/>
    <AuxValue name="FormSettings_generateFQN" type="java.lang.Boolean" value="true"/>
    <AuxValue name="FormSettings_generateMnemonicsCode" type="java.lang.Boolean" value="false"/>
    <AuxValue name="FormSettings_i18nAutoMode" type="java.lang.Boolean" value="false"/>
    <AuxValue name="FormSettings_layoutCodeTarget" type="java.lang.Integer" value="1"/>
    <AuxValue name="FormSettings_listenerGenerationStyle" type="java.lang.Integer" value="0"/>
    <AuxValue name="FormSettings_variablesLocal" type="java.lang.Boolean" value="false"/>
    <AuxValue name="FormSettings_variablesModifier" type="java.lang.Integer" value="2"/>
  </AuxValues>

  <Layout>
    <DimensionLayout dim="0">
      <Group type="103" groupAlignment="0" attributes="0">
          <EmptySpace min="0" pref="400" max="32767" attributes="0"/>
      </Group>
    </DimensionLayout>
    <DimensionLayout dim="1">
      <Group type="103" groupAlignment="0" attributes="0">
          <EmptySpace min="0" pref="300" max="32767" attributes="0"/>
      </Group>
    </DimensionLayout>
  </Layout>
</Form>
```

Além disso, você pode aprender qual é a estrutura do arquivo `.form` a medida que você manipula o construtor de GUI do Netbeans ao analisar como o XML é alterado e como estas alterações se refletem no código Java, mas não vou entrar em muitos detalhes nisso pois já está um tanto fora do propósito da pergunta.

Comment: resposta muito precisa. Obrigado.